# wso2 bps or WSO2 Process Center

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

Seems WSO2 are working on a new product called process center. Is it a new product to replace BPS?

I am working on bps3.2, and should I switch to process center? 
If switch to process center, how do I migrate my work, including bpel process and human task?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 BPS and WSO2 PC (Process center) are two separate products and will be used in separate phases of business process life cycle. For example BPS handles execution of business processes (runtime), while PC more focused on creating,managing,searching and analytic of business processes.

There was a talk on PC during recent wso2con.

https://youtu.be/sWIAeNR59YE

You can download WSO2 PC M1 from following site.

http://wso2.com/products/process-center/